# "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined"

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

My Flask HTML forms were rendering fine. However, after adding the form section in the footer, I get the error above whenever I click the 'about' link on the home page (index.html). Btw the homepage is rendering fine.

**This is my understanding of the issue:**
I have included the "footer.html" template in my code's "about.html" page.  When I include a template in another template, it shares the context of the included template. In this case, "about.html" includes "footer.html," but it doesn't have direct access to the 'form' variable that I defined in the / (home) route, which is why the home route can render and not the about page.

To resolve this issue, I must explicitly pass the 'form' variable to the 'about.html' template as shown:

```
@app.route("/about")
def about():
    form = CreatePNewsLetterEmailForm()  # Create the form here as well
    return render_template("about.html", form=form)
```

**However, this is not what I am aiming for**. Passing the form variable explicitly in multiple routes is repetitive and may not be the most efficient solution. I know Flask's context processors can avail the form globally to all templates without passing it explicitly in every route. Still, I don't know how to apply it.

The only solution that came close to mine was this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698772/jinja2-exceptions-undefinederror-form-is-undefined-error-in-python-flask], but I have rendered the form in the home route.

**Here is my code:**

**Flask server**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email
from flask_ckeditor import CKEditorField
import email_validator


class CreateNewsLetterEmailForm(FlaskForm):
    user_email = StringField(validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    submit = SubmitField("Sign Up")


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    # Newsletter Subs
    form = CreateNewsLetterEmailForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user_email = form.user_email.data

    return render_template("index.html", form=form)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")
```

**header.html template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>E-Commerce</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/CSS/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <section id="header">
        <a href="#"><img src="static/assets/images/logo.png" class="logo" alt=""></a>
        <div>
            <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{url_for('shop')}}">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{url_for('about')}}">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="mobile-view">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a>
            <i id="menu-bar" class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**footer.html template**

```
<section id="newsletter" class="feature-products-padding">
    <div class="news-text">
        <h4>Never Miss Out: Sign Up Now !</h4>
        <p>Join Our Email List for Shop Updates and <span>Exclusive Specials.</span></p>
    </div>
    <form class="email-capture-form" action="{{url_for('home')}}" method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="email-contact-form">
            {{ form.user_email(placeholder="Your email address...") }}
            <button>Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
<footer class="feature-products-padding">
    <div>content</div>
</footer>
<script src="/static/js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.html template**

```
{% include 'header.html' %}

    <section id="promotion">
        <h4>Trade-Up Special</h4>
        <h2>Value Galore:</h2>
        <h1>All Products Included</h1>
        <p>Unlock Extra Savings with Coupons & Up to 70% Off</p>
        <button type="button" class="normal" id="shopButton" >Shop Now</button>
    </section>
 

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

**about.html**

```
{% include 'header.html'%}

    <div>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```